# R testthat overwrite internal base functions

Tags: r, r-package, testthat

I'm writing a package which compares requested packages to available packages. That is, I can ask for 'mgsub == 1.5.0' and I want to see if I already have that version of a package installed before taking any action. I'm determining the already installed packages by looking at `installed.packages()[,3]`

I'm trying to be a good developer and write unit tests. While I can control what packages I want to install, I cannot control what packages are already installed. So, I need a way to, for testing purposes only, overwrite what comes out of `installed.packages()`. My initial thought was to add this code to the top of the unit tests as a way to hack around it.

```
installed.packages <- function(){return(INST)}
INST = structure(c("mgsub", "lexRankr", "readOffice",
                   "lib1", "lib1", "lib1",
                   "1.5.1.3", "0.4.1", "0.2.2"),
                 .Dim = c(3L, 3L),
                 .Dimnames = list(c("mgsub", "lexRankr", "readOffice"),
                                  c("Package", "LibPath", "Version")))
```

But, this doesn't work. testthat continues to use my actual list of installed packages instead of this set.

I tried using `testthat::setup` to initialize the function, but that didn't work either.

I tried `expect_is(installed.packages <- function(){return(INST)},'function')` to see if that would modify the search path in place. No dice.

Is there a way that I can, without adding extra inputs to my functions, control what my functions see as the currently installed packages for testing purposes only?

Comment: Can't you do your testing on purely simulated output from a hypothetical call to `installed.packages` and not actually call the function at all?

Comment: On the helper function I could, but the main function gets that information all on it's own, I was trying to control it for calling it from there.